# Edit a GPO with a script

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

Is it possible to use a batch file to edit a local GPO ?

**What I am exactly trying to do:**

- I want to create a "New Software Restriction Policies".
- Change a parameter value in the "Enforcement".
- Add a new path rule with a specific path.

**I am not looking for you to create the script. I just want to know if this is possible to do it with a batch file & and some idea to help me start with this task.**

This procedure is not really complicated and can be done manually. Given that I have to apply these change for a lot of computer, I am looking for a fastest way than doing it from the "gpedit.msc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible to edit the local GPO using a Batch script.  Simply manipulate the GPO by editing the registry keys.  **Note:** Depending upon the GPO setting changed through the registry, you may need to log the user off before the change takes effect.

**Step 1**

- Download the Microsoft Group Policy Setting Reference (Registry Keys List): 
   
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25250

**Step 2**

- Get the policy registry location from the Spreadsheet
  e.g. `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient!AppendToMultiLabelName`

**Step 3**

- Use the `reg add` command to edit the values as you need
  e.g. `@reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient" /v AppendToMultiLabelName /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

**Note**

- You may need to edit the GPO registry key in both the `Machine` and `User` section of the registry along with the `WOW` section.
  e.g. `@reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient" /v AppendToMultiLabelName /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f & @reg add "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient" /v AppendToMultiLabelName /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f & @for /f "delims=" %A in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects" /k /f "*Machine" ^| find /i "HKEY"') do @reg add "%~A\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient" /v AppendToMultiLabelName /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f & @reg add "%~A\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient" /v AppendToMultiLabelName /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

Breakdown of example:

- Update the value in the default location
- Update the value in the secondary location for 64-bit OS

  - Loop through the User GPOs

    - Update the value based on the default location
    - Update the value based on the secondary location for 64-bit OS

**[Source](http://davidruhmann.com/2014/01/edit-group-policy-by-script/)**

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot. Now I know where to start ! :)